# Set up a smtp (mail) delivery server

Tags: email, smtp

this question could probably be simple but frankly I don't know exactly what it is.
This is my scenario:
I have multiple devices like: UPS, router, switch,... and they all have option for me to configure sending email notification to my email address.
I want to setup a smtp server to receive email notification from those devices and send directly to my email address, perfectly without authentication to my organization's email server.
What is such server called? I did the google look up and returned some results like "smtp relay" but those things are much complicated than what I need.

Answer (score 1):

That is indeed called a mail or smtp relay server.

If you only send email to a single address such as you@example.com : you don’t need to configure a relay server at all. Your existing mailserver for @example.com (technically the primary MX record for the example.com domain)  will accept and deliver, without any authentication, smtp messages and emails addressed to you@example.com.

Use that existing mail server in the settings of your devices as the smtp server and you’re done.

Comment: thank you for reply. Can you show me how to verify that? I did the nslookup with mx query to my email domain address and tested using telnet to it and failed

Comment: Most current mail servers are, in an effort to prevent spam, quite particular about clients using a correct SMTP exchange which may be difficult to emulate with telnet. If you can't connect to the SMTP port, TCP 25, check your firewalls.